# Suppress PHP Errors' HTML tags when running from CLI

Tags: php, debugging, command-line-interface

When I run `php -l someFile` on the CLI, the output is marked up with HTML tags:

```
$ php -l someFile.php 
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in <b>/home/someUser/public_html/someFile.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />
Errors parsing someFile.php
$
```

How can I suppress these HTML tags? I am actually using a custom `php.ini` for the parsing (not shown in example to simplify), so if a php.ini modification will solve the issue then that is fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, Hakra. The two issues are related, but each one pertains to a different environment and the place to put the configuration item is different. In the linked question, there is no mention of the CLI or the `-d` flag, so even if one were to know the `html_errors` option, he wouldn't know what to do with it on the CLI!.

Comment: Duplicate will not mean that your question disappears (nor that your question is bad, which it isn't). It's more that we group these related questions more together on the site. In an ideal world, these would be merged.

Comment: I realise that, I'm not afraid of being marked dupe! However, I don't think that these questions should be merged as one is "how to X in environment Y" for which the answer is Z, but the other is "how to X in environment A" for which the answer is B. Both are asking about X, but in different environments and with different answers.

Comment: One vote for close, this merely is a suggestion of a possible duplicate. It also adds the link on the right under "Linked", the "Related" column is not of much use. It's not all black and white.

Comment: The link under Linked is because you linked to it, hakra!

Comment: I linked it because I close voted it. So you see, catching two flies in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set html_errors to false in your ini file http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors

```
$ php -dhtml_errors=0 -l someFile
```